# How to hide sensitive data from node.conf?

Tags: corda

Can someone please give me an example for `corporatePasswordStore` that is mentioned here:
https://docs.corda.net/node-administration.html?fbclid=IwAR0gRwe5BtcWO0NymZVyE7_yMfthu2xxnU832vZHdbuv17S-wPXgb7iVZSs#id2

I've been doing a lot of research in the last few days on how to hide the plain passwords from `node.conf`; it's a new topic for me and this is what I came up with so far:

1. Create a priv/pub key with `gpg2`
2. Create a password store with `pass` (using the key that I generated earlier).
3. Store all the plain passwords from `node.conf` inside that password store.
4. Replace the plain passwords in `node.conf` with environment variables (e.g. `keyStorePassword = ${KEY_PASS}`)
5. Create a script file (e.g. `start_node.sh`) that will do the following:

   a. Set an environment variable to one of the passwords from the password store: `export key_store_password=$(pass node.conf/keyStorePassword)`
   b. Start the node: `java -jar corda.jar`
   c. Restart the gpg agent to clear the cached passwords, otherwise you can get any password from the store without passing the passphrase: `gpgconf --reload gpg-agent`

**Pros:**

1. Using the bash file `start_node.sh` allows to set many passwords as environment variables at once (e.g. keyStore, trustStore, db passwords, RPC user password)
2. Since we are running the bash file with `bash start_node.sh` and not `source start_node.sh`, the environment variable is not exposed to the parent process (i.e. you cannot read that environment variable value inside the terminal where you ran bash start_node.sh
3. History commands are not enabled by default inside bash scripts.

**Cons:**

You no longer can have a service that automatically starts on VM startup, because the `start_node.sh` script will ask for the passphrase for your gpg key that was used to encrypt the passwords inside the password store (i.e. it's an interactive script).

Am I over-complicating this? Do you have an easier approach? Is it even necessary to hide the plain passwords?

I'm using Corda open source so I can't use the Configuration Obfuscator (which is for Enterprise only): https://docs.corda.r3.com/tools-config-obfuscator.html#configuration-obfuscator (edited)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a detailed article here: https://blog.b9lab.com/enabling-corda-security-with-nodes-configuration-file-412ce6a4371c, which covers the following topics:

1. Enable SSL for database connection.
2. Enable SSL for RPC connection.
3. Enable SSL for Corda webserver.
4. Enable SSL for Corda standalone shell.
5. Hide plain text passwords.
6. Set permissions for RPC users.