# Can I delete the node.conf file after starting Corda Node?

Tags: corda

For security, Can I delete the node.conf file after starting Node?
I do not  want to show the DB information in the node.conf file to others.

Comment: I tried to achieve the same but couldn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618997/how-to-hide-sensitive-data-from-node-conf.  If you're using Enterprise edition, then have a look at this: https://docs.corda.r3.com/tools-config-obfuscator.html

Comment: And no, you cannot delete `node.conf`.

Comment: @Adel Rustum Thx a lot .it is useful for me . : https://docs.corda.net/node-administration.html?highlight=key_pass#id2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adel also mentioned, you cannot delete the `node.conf` file